# Obtain $f_X(x)$ and calculate $P(X \leq 3), P(X \geq1)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

If $\qquad$ $F_X(x) = \begin{cases}0 \qquad if \qquad x < -1, \\ \frac{1}{3} \qquad if \qquad -1 \leq x < 1, \\ \frac{1}{2} \qquad if \qquad 1 \leq x < 3 \\ \frac{3}{4} \qquad if \qquad 3 \leq x < 5, \\ 1 \qquad if \qquad 5 \leq x \end{cases}$

Obtain $f_X(x)$ and calculate $P(X \leq 3), P(X \geq1)$

If we graph $F_X(x)$ we can see that is a discontinuous function so it would be a "mix" function, continuos because it takes all real numbers but discountinous in some points. Knowing this how can I find $f_X(x)$ ?

Comment: what do you mean by $f_X$?

Comment: $f_X(x)$ is the probability function and $F_X(x)$ is the distribution function.

Comment: $f_X(x)$ will be a probability mass function with

$f_X(-1) = \frac{1}{3}$

$f_X(1) = \frac{1}{6}$

$f_X(3) = \frac{1}{4}$

$f_X(5) = \frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $F_X$ is piecewise constant, we see that $X$ is a discrete random variable. It takes values at the jump discontinuities of $F$: $-1$, $1$, $3$, and $5$. For each of these points we have $\mathbb P(X=x) = F_X(x) - F_X(x-)$, where $F_X(x-)$ denotes the left-limit $\lim_{y\to x^-} F_X(y)$. So
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X = -1) &= F_X(-1) - F_X(-1-) = \frac13-0 = \frac13\\
\mathbb P(X = 1) &= F_X(1) - F_X(1-) = \frac12-\frac13 = \frac16\\
\mathbb P(X = 3) &= F_X(3) - F_X(3-) = \frac34-\frac12 = \frac14\\
\mathbb P(X = 5) &= F_X(5) - F_X(5-) = 1 - \frac34 = \frac 14.
\end{align}
It follows that
$$
\mathbb P(X\leqslant 3) = 1 - \mathbb P(X>3) = 1 - \mathbb P(X=5) = 1 -\frac14 = \frac34
$$
and
$$
\mathbb P(X\geqslant 1) = 1 - \mathbb P(X<1) = 1 - \mathbb P(X=-1) = 1-\frac13 = \frac23.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $F_X(t) = \mathbb P(X \le t)$, and since $\mathbb P(X < t) = \mathbb P( \bigcup_n (X \le t-\frac{1}{n})) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb P(X \le t-\frac{1}{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty}F(t-\frac{1}{n})$, and since $F_X$ is monotone, then we get $\mathbb P(X<t) = \lim_{s \to t^-} F_X(s) := F_X(t-)$

So we have:

$\mathbb P(X \le 3 ) = F_X(3) = \frac{3}{4}$ (just read from the formula)

$\mathbb P(X \ge 1) = 1 - \mathbb P(X < 1) = 1 - F_X(1-) = 1 - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3} $

Now, note that in terms of CDF, we have $f_X(x) = \mathbb P(X=x) = \mathbb P(\{X \le x\} \cap (\{X < x \})^c) = \mathbb P(X \le x) - \mathbb P(X < x) = F_X(x) - F_X(x-)$

And we have to again, read it from the formula. Obviously, it can only be non-zero in the discontinuity points of $F_X$, so we have to check only points $x \in \{-1,1,3,5\}$

$f_X(-1) = \frac{1}{3} - 0 = \frac{1}{3}$,

$f_X(1) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6}$,

$f_X(3) = \frac{1}{4}$

$f_X(5) = \frac{1}{4}$.

Fortunatelly $$ \sum_{x \in \mathbb R : f_X(x) \neq 0} f_X(x) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{4+3+3+2}{12} = 1$$

As you can see, we can easily generalize. Value $f_X(x)$ for any random variable $X$ (not only in your case) is exactly the value of "jump" on the graph of $F_X$ at point $x$. Easily seen, it's always $0$ where $F_X$ is continuous, and non-zero iff $F_X$ is discontinuous at that point.